# How to get the hexadecimal file signature of a .swift file?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I need to get the hexadecimal file signature (and offset) of a macOS Xcode `.swift` file. How does one go about this?

Reference: https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the magic numbers by looking at the head of a hex dump:
`xxd prog.swift | head`